# Outlook android app - emails disappear after opening in desktop

Tags: microsoft-outlook, android, microsoft-outlook-2007

I've an issue with my outlook android app:

- I've set-up an IMAP email account of my website(my personal website/domain).
- I've also setup outlook(2007) for the same on my desktop.

I do receive new emails on my phone. But the moment when I open the same email on my desktop, the emails on my phone inbox disappear. And BTW the data file is set to PST on my desktop outlook.

Any help? How to retain emails on my phone without them disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

I'd check settings in both apps, your Android app and Outlook.

- Ensure the mobile app isn't filtering on UNREAD messages, but showing all.
- Ensure Outlook isn't configured to delete messages upon reading.
- Ensure both apps are configured to access the mailbox via IMAP, not POP3.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you have solved your problem or not, but I had to reboot my android and found most of my emails in outlook weren't there. It only showed a few days worth in the inbox.

But i went to the burger button, then settings and looked at the sync setting. I changed to all and I can now see all my emails in outlook on android.

I hope this helps someone.